# How to set null value product in last in sorting on product listing page?

Tags: php, magento, sorting, magento-1.7

Hello i have main 4 product like

```
     product_name  attribute_name attribute_value
----------------------------------------------------------
     test1           catname        abc
     test2           catname        ccc
     test3           catname        ###
     test4           catname        bbb
```

when i  am trying sort products  by **catname** on product listing page than i am getting null value product **test3** first , but i need it in last. i have to ignore null attribute value.

I have try in toolbar.phtml for **asc** and **desc** but its not which i want.

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

You can try as

```
 ORDER BY if(attribute_value = '' or attribute_value is null,1,0),attribute_value ,product_name
```

Comment: can you explain me where to put this code in magento??

Comment: In maganto I guess its addAttributeToSort() where the order by is added. I am not so good in maganto. But if you are able to add the above code then it will sort as u wanted.